# Alternative to @Qualifier in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have this scenario

1. team A is implementing an `interface Vehicle` as `ClassAVehicle`
2. team B is implementing a dashboard service in which it uses vehicle implementation

Now team A have new implementation of Vehicle as **ClassBVehicle**. And team B wants to use it. One way I know is that use of @Qualifier annotation. But for this I require to change team B's code.
So do I have **tight coupling** here? Can I have some **XML based configuration** so that team B's code resolves new ClassBVehicle instance automatically?

```java
interface Vehicle{
    int getNoTyre();
}
```

```java
class ClassAVehicle{
    int getNoTyre(){
        return 1;
    }
}
```

```java
class ClassBVehicle{
    int getNoTyre(){
        return 2;
    }
}
```

```java
class Dashboard{
    // Here everything is fine until classBVehicle is not there
    // Now I want to use new classBVehicle.
    // One way I see is that using @Qualifier but will it not be tight coupling? 
    @Autowired
    Vehicle oldAInstance;
}
```

Comment: i hope i don't fully understand the question.. is team B using the **implementation** instead of the interface? That's the whole point of interfaces, so if the answer to that question is yes, then yes, you have tight coupling. Team B should use the interface in their code and actually not know the implementation. Team A is responsible for the implementing the interface. However it may look like.

Comment: Hey I have added some code sample. Apology for late reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use xml to define bean, your way is good to decouple. Another way is that you can use ApplicationContext to get bean dynamically in annotation program. There are two way to getBean with beanName or beanClass. The below is sample:

```java
@Service
public class BService {

    private Vehicle vo;

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;


    public void getVehicle(String beanName){
        this.vo =  (Vehicle) context.getBean(beanName);
    }


    public void getVehicle(Class beanClz){
        this.vo = (Vehicle) context.getBean(beanClz);
    }

    public void print(){
        System.out.println("---class is "+vo.getClass());
    }

}

public interface Vehicle  {
}

@Component
public class OneVehicle implements Vehicle{
}

@Component
public class TwoVehicle implements Vehicle{
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringDependenciesExampleApplication implements ApplicationRunner {


    @Autowired
    BService bService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringDependenciesExampleApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments applicationArguments) throws Exception {
        bService.getVehicle("oneVehicle");
        bService.print();
    }
}


// output is ---class is class OneVehicle
```

Comment: I need something like this. But still I need to change the team B's code. Can I do above adjustment into some external xml file and that will be loaded into Team B's code automatically?

Comment: What your adjustment is  to control bService use which vehicle without restart app? If you put adjustment info in xml file, you should restart your app to reload file. Maybe you can use -D param or restful interface to receive adjustment info so it is actually automatic without restart app.